# Handcraft RNN with attention to extract central element

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, attention

I am trying to formulate an RNN that uses attention to easily detect the central element of a sequence. For an RNN alone this is not an easy task but with attention, it should be but I am not entirely certain how to design it. The goal of this question is to understand both mechanisms better.

---

So for example I have `(10,20,30)` or `(10,20,30,40,50)` given as input sequence.
At input 30 the RNN should output 20 at position 50 -> 30 and so forth.

---

My idea for the RNNs hidden state is to just increase it by 1. The hidden state h would just be a scalar.
e.g. (10,20,30) produces the states (1,2,3)

But now I am stuck as attention should work with the input and the hidden state. What I would need as output would be scored (0,1,0) * (10,20,30) = 20.
The scoring function I come up with would be `s(h, number, i) = 1 if h/2 == i else 0`.
But there I am using the index as an additional parameter / positional encoding and wondering if I can do it without it.

---

What could be other approaches to handcraft an RNN with attention to extracting the half-position element of a sequence?

Answer (score 0):

One can view the hidden states just like stated in the question as made up from a linear increasing counter and the input.
The **query will be the current position *n*** and **key the position count** in the hidden state *t*:

```
a(t, n) = I(t == n/2) = w_t
```

where I is the indicator function.
The output can be seen as the `sum over all w_t * x_t = x_t`.

To be strict the **value=x_t** can be stored in the hidden states which would be

```
h_t = (x_t, t)
```